# Hardware Acceleration for Headless Chrome on WSL2 Docker

Tags: docker, google-chrome, puppeteer, nvidia, wsl-2

my target is to server-side-render a frame of a WebGL2 application in a performant way.
To do so, I'm using Puppeteer with headless Chrome inside a Docker container running Ubuntu 20.04.4 on WSL2 on Windows 10 22H2.
However, I can't get any hardware acceleration to become active.
It seems that Chrome doesn't detect my Nvidia GTX1080 card, while on the host system with `headless: false` it's being used and increases render performance drastically.

I have followed the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/htc-research-engineering-blog/nvidia-docker-on-wsl2-f891dfe34ab) to install the CUDA toolkit on WSL2.

A container spun up using `sudo docker run --gpus all nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody nbody -gpu -benchmark` uses the GTX1080.

Running `nvidia-smi` inside the container shows the following:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.65       Driver Version: 527.37       CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P8    10W /  N/A |    871MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
```

Using flags like

```
--ignore-gpu-blocklist
--enable-gpu-rasterization
--enable-zero-copy
--use-gl=desktop / --use-gl=egl
```

did not solve the problem.

I also tried libosmesa6 with `--use-gl=osmesa` which had no effect.

I'm starting my container with docker-compose including the following section into the service's block:

```
deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

Chrome version is `HeadlessChrome/108.0.5351.0`.
The Chrome WebGL context's WEBGL_debug_renderer_info tells me
vendor: `Google Inc. (Google)`
renderer: `ANGLE (Google, Vulkan 1.3.0 (SwiftShader Device (Subzero) (0x0000C0DE)), SwiftShader driver)`

Visiting chrome://gpu with Puppeteer shows me the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4spNw.png)

Any ideas what might still be missing to have Chrome use the GPU for hardware acceleration?